# Leaflet plus Turf.js - dynamically set bounds based on data points

Tags: leaflet, turfjs

I'm new to Turf.js but have used leaflet before. Looking to move my Google maps over to leafet/turf.js

I'm trying to dynamically set the initial map view by using getBounds as per leaflet, but when using Turf.js, I get an error 'line.getBounds' is not a function.

I've also tried using bbox, to get the bounding box of my datapoints, and whilst I can draw the box on the screen, I can't seem set the initial view to it. I can set the initial view as a static point.

```
        //Some Points
        var somePoints = [
                [-3.535,55.62],
                [-3.54,55.61],
                [-3.547,55.6],
                [-3.55,55.59],
                [-3.57,55.58]
                ];

        var features = turf.points(somePoints);
        var center = turf.center(features);


        var map = L.map('map').setView([55.6, -3.55], 12);  

    
        L.tileLayer(
            'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org" target=blank>OpenStreetMap</a> Contributors',
            maxZoom: 18,
        }).addTo(map);
          

        var line = turf.lineString(somePoints);
        var options = {units: 'miles'};
        L.geoJSON(line).addTo(map);
        
        var along = turf.along(line, 1.25, options);
            L.geoJSON(along).addTo(map).bindTooltip("my tooltip text");
         
            along = turf.along(line, 2.123, options);
            L.geoJSON(along).addTo(map).bindTooltip("12345");

            var bbox = turf.bbox(line);
            var bboxPolygon = turf.bboxPolygon(bbox);
            
            L.geoJSON(bboxPolygon ).addTo(map)
            

            var features = turf.points(somePoints);
            var center = turf.center(features);
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated code - I needed to find the bounds of the turf.js object

```
        //path coords
        var coords = [
                [-3.535,55.62],
                [-3.54,55.61],
                [-3.547,55.6],
                [-3.55,55.59],
                [-3.57,55.58]
                ];

        var features = turf.points(coords );
        var center = turf.center(features);

        var map = L.map('map');  
    
        L.tileLayer(
            'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org" target=blank>OpenStreetMap</a> Contributors',
            maxZoom: 18,
        }).addTo(map);
          

        var line = turf.lineString(coords);     
        var options = {units: 'miles'}; 


        L.geoJSON(line).addTo(map);
        
        var along = turf.along(line, 1.25, options);
            L.geoJSON(along).addTo(map).bindTooltip("my tooltip text");
         
            along = turf.along(line, 2.123, options);
            L.geoJSON(along).addTo(map).bindTooltip("12345");

            // get center x/y
            var features = turf.points(coords);
            var center = turf.center(features);
            var centroid_xy = center.geometry.coordinates;
            var x = centroid_xy[0];
            var y = centroid_xy[1];

            
            // get bounds 
                var bbox = turf.bbox(line);
                var b0 = bbox[0];
                var b1 = bbox[1];
                var b2 = bbox[2];
                var b3 = bbox[3];                           


            L.marker([55.62, -3.535]).bindPopup("Test marker").addTo(map);
                var mapMarker2 = L.icon({
                iconSize:     [16, 16],
                iconAnchor:   [8, 8],
            });

                                            
            map.setView([y, x], 13);
            map.fitBounds([[b1, b0],[b3, b2]]);
```